# Django NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Tags: python, django

When I try to follow [this tutorial](http://ghickman.co.uk/2012/07/22/google-oauth2-sso-with-django.html) to install Google-auth2 on my Django 1.4 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/home/ubuntu/xx/settings.py", line 140, in <module>
    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID']
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

This line is:

```
139- LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

**140- GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID']**

141- GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET']
142- GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = ['mydomain.org']
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You try to use *something* from module `os`, which is not imported, thus you cannot use it.

In order to fix this problem, add an import of that module somewhere at the beginning of `settings.py`:

```
import os
```

---

Additionally, if you don't have `GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` in `os.environ`, don't load it from there. Instead, set it directly in `settings.py`:

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'your-actual-client-id-value'
```

Or, you can set it first, in your shell, before running the script:

```
export GOOGLE_OATH2_CLIENT_ID='your-actual-client-id-value'
```